Hide parent nodes if child has no data
I have an apex tree with 3 layers: (Apex version 22.1)
BU_NAME ORG_UNIT_NAME DEPT_NAME

Source Table:
DEPT_BU_LIST
DEPT_ID BU_NAME ORG_UNIT_NAME   DEPT_NAME   Files
1        A_BU   AX_ORG          A1_DEPT     XYZ.xls
2        B_BU   BX_ORG          A2_DEPT     ABX.xls
3        C_BU   CX_ORG          A3_DEPT     ABC.xls
4        C_BU   CX_ORG          A4_DEPT     ABD.xls


CREATE TABLE DEPT_BU_LIST 
( DEPT_ID NOT NULL ENABLE,
BU_NAME VARCHAR2(100), ORG_UNIT_NAME VARCHAR2(100), DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(100),FILES VARCHAR2(100));


INSERT INTO DEPT_BU_LIST VALUES
(1,'A_BU','AX_ORG','A1_DEPT','XYZ.xls');
INSERT INTO DEPT_BU_LIST VALUES
(1,'B_BU','AY_ORG','A1_DEPT','ABX.xls');
INSERT INTO DEPT_BU_LIST VALUES
(1,'C_BU','CX_ORG','A3_DEPT','ABC.xls');
INSERT INTO DEPT_BU_LIST VALUES
(1,'C_BU','CX_ORG','A4_DEPT','ABD.xls');

And this is the main tree query:
select CASE
       WHEN connect_by_isleaf = 1
       THEN 0
       WHEN level = 1
       THEN 1
       ELSE -1
       END AS status,
       LEVEL,
       child AS title,
       NULL AS icon,
       NULL as tooltip,
       'javascript:$s("P1_SELECTED_NODE","'
       || CASE LEVEL
          WHEN 1 THEN child
          WHEN 2 THEN parent || '|' || child
          WHEN 3 THEN CONNECT_BY_ROOT child || '|' || parent || '|' || child
          END 
       || '")' AS link 
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT bu_name, parent, child, depth
  FROM   (SELECT d.*, NULL AS root FROM DEPT_BU_LIST d)
         UNPIVOT (
           (bu_name, parent, child) FOR depth IN (
             (bu_name, root, bu_name) AS 1,
             (bu_name, bu_name, org_unit_name) AS 2,
             (bu_name, org_unit_name, dept_name) AS 3
           )
         )
)
START WITH DEPTH = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent
AND        PRIOR depth + 1 = depth
AND        PRIOR bu_name = bu_name
ORDER SIBLINGS BY child

Here DEPT_NAME is the lowest child node. In the same page on right side i have an interactive grid.
So when i click on DEPT_NAME, corresponsing Files should show.
If i click on A1_dEPT, it should show XYZ.xls in the grid.
select Files from dept_bu_list where 
(:P1_BU_NAME is not null or bu_name=:P1_BU_NAME) and
(:P1_ORG_NAME is not null or org_name=:P1_ORG_NAME) and
(:P1_DEPT_NAME is not null or dept_name=:P1_DEPT_NAME) 

Now it works fine, however if a node does not have a file, it shouldn't show at all.
So if for A_BU, AX_ORG,A1_DEPT there's no File, all the 3 parent nodes shouldn't show.
For C_BU->CX_ORG->A3_DEPT-> No file
C_BU->CX_ORG->A4_DEPT-> file exists.In this case, C_BU->CX_ORG->A4_dEPT will show. A3_DEPT won't show.
How can this be achieved.
Please let me know if any other info is needed.

ok thanks for the info. But the question is valid right? I need help with this. Kindly do not close it.

Consider researching your question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Changed tags - this is not so much an APEX question as a sql question.

Please [edit] the question and explain clearly the logic you are trying to implement and the expected output. All the rows in your table have a value in the FILES column so all the rows should be shown. I got this far but have no idea what problem you want to solve.
